# send array from laravel controller to javascript as get request result

Tags: javascript

I have a get request with javascript:

```
(function () {
    $('select[name=Subtest]').change(function () {

        var url = '{{ url('Subtest')}}' + '/' + $(this).val() + '/options/';

        jQuery.get(url, function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                alert(value['name'];
            });
        });
    });
})();
```

and my controller has this code

```
public function getOptions(Subtest $subtest)
{
    $optionCategories = $subtest->optionCategories()->get();
    $data = [];
    foreach ($optionCategories as $optionCategory) {
        $name = $optionCategory->option()->select('name')->get();
        $data = [
            'name' => $name
        ] ;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

I send data array to javascript and want to get `data['name']` each time but Now with this code I get undefined How I can solved this?

Comment: Need to return json from server

Comment: @charlietfl can you send me code?I'm new in javascript and son't know How I can do it

Comment: Research how to send json in laravel